# Are these spots on cucumber plant leaves from insects?

Tags: cucumbers

Some of my cucumber plants have small spots on the lower leaves.

The affected leaves have small white/yellow spots on their edges, and a few spots on the leaves are dead. The dead spot had a yellow "halo".

Right now I just see this on a couple of leaves, but since I had to throw out all my cucumber plants last year I'm very much keeping a sharp eye on them.

When I google this, the most best matchin terms of how these spots look is Downey Mildew - but that on the other hand is described as mostly affecting late harvest.

This is indoors, and I have not seen a single insect.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the leaf underside is clear, then this doesn’t look like insect damage.

It looks very similar to sun damage, as if the leaves (especially wet) were exposed to very hot sun.

Comment: If these "dead" spots are sun damage, should I then not see these spots at all on the underside?

I do give them a shower now and then to brush off any "passengers", so this could be an explanation.